# Using .val() to set the number of iterations for .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field that contains a number.  I'm getting that value with the following code:

```
$("#myField").val()
//returns 3
```

I would like to use that value to set the number of iterations of my loop.  I tried the following:

```
$("#myField").val().each(function()...)
```

But I get nothing.

How do I set the number of iterations?

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < ($("#myField").val() * 1); i++) { }`

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach. **Why not just use a regular for loop?**

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < ~~$("#myField").val(); i++) { }` even shorter d:

Comment: @JarrodRoberson  I did state the problem.  I am using jQuery.  I wanted to see if there was a jQuery solution.  If I need to use javascript that's fine.  I noticed that you didn't offer any solutions, but only a criticism.  What you added was not helpful.

Comment: @JozefDúc and oMiKeY please do not answer in the comments. That's what the answer function is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using for loop. See an example:

```
var value = $(".myField").val()
for (var i=0; value > i; i++) {
  $('.otherElement').eq(i).addClass('iteration-'+i);
}
```

Comment: That worked.  Along with the other answers suggested.

Answer (score 0):

An example which uses jQuery `each()` method

```js
var val = 3; //$(".myField").val() 
var arr = Array.from(Array(val).keys());

$.each(arr, function(i) {
  console.log('Iteration ' + i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another way to iterate `n` times is by using the long arrow operator

```js
let n = $(".myField").val()
while (n --> 0)
  console.log(n)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class='myField' value='5' />
```